# Stop IntelliJ 11 adding "use strict" to every nested function definition when JSLint is enabled

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jslint

Anyone know how to stop IntelliJ 11 automatically adding `"use strict"` to every nested function definition I create when JSLint is enabled?

I have specified `'use strict'` in the outer closure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a workaround you can disable **Prefer Strict mode** in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `JavaScript` (available since IDEA 11.1.1).

Please [vote for the issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-10717) we've created.